# Extracting a pattern from output of an external command in Powershell

Tags: powershell

For my powershell script, I run an external command and look for a specific pattern in the output. For example:

The command "eraseDevice" gives me output like this:

```
Erasing Deployment... Erasing sector 0x080a8000 
Erasing sector 0x080c1000 
Erasing sector 0x080e1000 
Erasing sector 0x64010000 
Rebooting...
```

I want the number 0x080a8000 from this output. I have tried the following:

```
eraseDevice | select-string -simplematch -pattern 0x
```

which returns the lines that contain the hexadecimal number. I tried doing the following as well, but all of them return errors:

```
eraseDevice | select-string -simplematch -pattern 0x -totalcount 1 
eraseDevice | (select-string -simplematch -pattern 0x)[4] 
eraseDevice | (select-string -simplematch -pattern 0x).split()[4]
```

**Desired output:** 0x080a8000 from the first line.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want only the hexadecimal number from the first line of the output and not the three that follow?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` to get only the first line of output from `eraseDevice`:

```
eraseDevice | Select-Object -First 1;
```

Then pipe that into `Select-String` to find `'0x'` followed by exactly eight hexadecimal characters:

```
eraseDevice | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-String -Pattern '0x[0-9a-f]{8}'
```

`Select-String` returns instances of the [`MatchInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.aspx).  To retrieve just the matched number, access the `Value` property of the first element of the `Matches` collection:

```
eraseDevice `
    | Select-Object -First 1 `
    | Select-String -Pattern '0x[0-9a-f]{8}' `
    | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value };
```

Note that if you did want to extract the sector number from all lines of output, you could just remove `Select-Object` from the pipeline and leave the rest of the command unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

```
$r = [regex] "(0x[0-9a-f]+)"
$line = (eraseDevice | select -first 1)
$num = $r.match($line).groups[1].value
```